# Collapsing appendices chapters automatically in Texmaker

Tags: chapters, texmaker, automation

I'm wondering if it's possible to collapse automatically the appendices chapters in Texmaker when I open the software.

Example: I'd like to start Texmaker from the state in the second figure belove without clicking every time on the minus "-" on the left side of the chapters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry: What do you mean?

Comment: Hello @MS-SPO I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can at least close selectively before you leave TexMaker:

[image: Unfolding]

2. You can check `TexMaker.ini` and see, whether or not there are entries supporting what you need.
3. You can create and run a script:

[image: scripting]

For scripting see the last entry of TexMaker's help-page:

[image: javascript]

Comment: Hi @MS-SPO thank you for your reply. How can I selectively fold a single chapter by using an command in the configuration file TexMaker.ini?

Comment: Don’t know. Make an inspection, e.g. a) close TM with all chapters unfolded, b) copy TM.ini, c) repeat with one chapter closed, d) compare both ini files, e) find a way to overwrite parameters, should they exist. // BTW it‘s a nice question for TexMaker …